# Is the Scala's apply method only useful for hiding the new keyword?

Tags: scala

I have some code that looks like this:

```
  object Money {
    def apply(dollars: BigInt, cents: BigInt) = new Money(dollars, cents)
  }

  class Money(dollars: BigInt, cents: BigInt) {
    override def toString() = dollars + "." + cents
  }
```

I'm trying to understand the benefits of the apply function but so far can only think of it as a type of syntactic sugar so that I don't need to use the new operator to construct a Money object. That is, I don't see a lot of benefit in the apply function, as all it's doing for me is turning this:

```
val money = new Money(2, 50)
```

into:

```
val money = Money(2, 50)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: It is like a Factory method, you can change that (for example return a subclass of Money) without changing all the user code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't underestimate syntactic sugar. While it may be possible to accomplish most everything by directly calling `.apply()`, it's the sugar that makes it nice to use and easy to read.

Let's take functions, for example. **All functions are objects in Scala**. You could define a function the following way:

```
object add extends Function2[Int, Int, Int] {
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
}

val z = add(1, 2) // same as add.apply(1, 2)
```

This is about the same as what `def add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y` does. Allowing `()` to be syntactic sugar for the apply function lets functions be implemented as objects, yet behave naturally like functions when invoked.

As some comments have pointed out, there's also a convention in Scala that apply methods used directly on companion objects are frequently used for factory methods. Rather than instantiating a `new Foo(bar)` directly, calling `Foo.apply(bar)` or `Foo(bar)` may invoke more complex logic that creates an appropriate result for the given input, be that a Foo or some subclass of Foo.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apply)

```
In mathematics and computer science, Apply is a function that applies functions to arguments.
```

In the case of Scala language, apply() is used to connect Object-oriented and functional programming. In Scala, everything is an object, including functions:  Generally speaking the "apply" method is a convenient way to ensure that an object can act as a function.